# How to use JOIN statement in sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, join, c#-4.0

I have 2 tables.

Products- prod_id, prod_name, prod_pic, prod_price

Orders - Order_id, User_id, prod_id

I want to select prod_name, prod_pic, prod_price from Products where prod_id IN( select prod_id from Orders where User_id=123);

But I also want to select Order_id from Orders where User_id =123.

How can I do that simultaneously?

I will be binding the resulting data of 4 columns to a Gridview in ASP.NET using SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select prod_name, prod_pic, prod_price, orders.order_id from Products
join orders on orders.prodid = products.prodid
Where User_id=123
```